# convert rows to columns with comma as filed delimiter using Linux

Tags: linux, awk

```
server:~# cat file1.txt
abc
pqr
xyz
```

I would like to convert as below:

```
abc,pqr,xyz
```

I'm using below command

```
server:~# cat file1.txt | tr "\n" ", "
abc,pqr,xyz,server:~#
```

Plz note my input may contain n number of lines which we don't.

How can we achieve..

```
server:~# cat file1.txt | tr "\n" ", "
abc,pqr,xyz
server:~#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command

```
paste -sd, file1.txt
```

By default, `paste` pastes lines from multiple files side-by-side separated by tabs; the `-d` option sets an alternate delimiter and the `-s` option tells it to take lines **s**erially from one file at a time (or, as in this case, serially from a single file).

Comment: thanks, Its working. plz add explaination.

Answer (score 0):

`paste -sd,` is reasonable, but in case you want an alternative or to do more with the input than just combine lines:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? "," : ""), $0} END{print ""}' file
abc,pqr,xyz
```

Comment: Ed thanks - can you plz explain this ??

Comment: @Achar007 It seems pretty self-explanatory to me, what part of it don't you understand?